# Null/No SIFT descriptor and keypoints generated in python

Tags: python, opencv, sift, vlfeat

I am trying to create a codebook from a set of image patches. I have divided the images (Caltech 101) into 20 X 20 image patches. I want to create a SIFT descriptor for each patch. But for some of the image patches, it does not return any descriptor/keypoint. I have tried using OpenCV and vlfeat.
The behavior is same using any of the libraries.

Following is my code using OpenCV -

```
sift = cv2.SIFT()
img = cv2.imread('patch_temp.jpg',0)
imgptch = cv2.imread('image_patch.jpg',cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(imgptch,None)
print des
```

des is 'None'. Same is the case if I use vlfeat. 
Note : Above works if I use a different image. It returns None for some of the images (6 out of 10).

I have created the image patch using OpenCV indexing -

```
patch = img[0:20,0:20]
cv2.imwrite('image_patch.jpg',img)
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `sift.detectAndCompute` will *first* try to detect a SIFT keypoint *then* compute a descriptor at the *found* location.

This is not what you want: you want to have a descriptor for each patch.
You can hand craft the keypoint locations first (by adjusting their `pt` property to the center of your patches and adjusting their `size` property to your patch size).
Then, call only the descriptor extractor on this set of locations.